# Android : Viewpager with fragments calling asynctask

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

i've viewpager which calls fragment (by a fragmentpagermanager) in which I start an asynctask.

In the function

```
setUserVisibleHint
```

I'm launching my asynctask, and it's running. The problem is, the view pager is loading several fragments (i've one fragment, I'm calling the same, just datas change) in the same time, and when the asynctask is finished, my listview don't shows data, my data are present in the next fragment... not in the current fragment.

So the problem is, I don't arrive to launch the asynctask for the current fragment, and to show them directly.

It's hard to explain, i hope some understands :D

Comment: post your code to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: thx, but i solved my problem... hard to explain, but it was stupid error.